# Get client MAC address from express request object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to grab the MAC address from the incoming request object. My application runs behind nginx proxy so for getting IP address i use the below syntax and it works fine.

```
var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

Similarly is there a way to get the MAC address of the request that's been made. Came across this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac and i'm not sure if that would help. Fundamentally i need to grab the MAC and IP address of every incoming request.

Comment: HTTP requests don't contain any MAC addresses?

Comment: What would you need it for?

Comment: @Bergi i'm trying to get the IP and MAC address to identify the end user's device from which the request is made.. the app which i'm working on deals with subscriptions and i'm trying capture the number of subscriptions made in a given day so when the request is made from a desktop or any hand held devices then for each request i'm trying to gather this information

Comment: You can get the IP, but not the MAC address. It's not public for good reason. If you want to distinguish desktops from handhelds, then you should use other mechanisms.

Comment: thanks @Bergi, may be i need to use "user agent" to identify the device from which the request is made

Comment: Yes. User agent string, screen size, anything else. There are so many approaches. Try to find a library that does it for you, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible. MAC addresses are not transmitted over the Internet.

See: https://superuser.com/questions/510920/is-my-mac-address-public-when-browsing-the-internet or https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36583/can-a-website-still-detect-my-real-mac-address-even-if-i-use-different-virtual-m

(And `getmac` will only give you the MAC of your *server's* network interface.)

Comment: so in that case since i'm trying to get the MAC address of the device from which the request is made, is there any plugin or package that can help with this requirement.

Comment: As I just said, this information doesn't exist on your side, so you can't get the MAC address, end of story. - (Only if you have control over the devices which send the request, you could of course add code to send the MAC address as a parameter.)

Comment: Nothing is impossible. An alternative question might be: how does Paypal get the mac address of its clients which it uses as an account security procedure?

Comment: I don't think they can get your MAC address just using your browser - maybe they use a Java applet you have to authorize, or some other piece of coding running on the client's machine? The point is, "nothing is impossible" doesn't make information appear out of thin air. The MAC address isn't transmitted over the Internet - your router can see it, or your ISP if you are connected directly (e.g. via 3G), but the next hop already can't, they would see your router's or your ISP's MAC address, etc. Nothing is forwarding your MAC address to the next piece of network hardware in the chain.

Comment: And if the client is connected directly?

Comment: There is no such thing unless you are referring to connecting two computers via a crossover LAN cable

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get it from request, but you could get it first and then store it in `req.session` for example.

How to get the mac address:

```
const os = require( 'os' );
var mac_ip = os.networkInterfaces()['en3'][3]['mac'];
console.log('ip_test: ', ip_test);
req.session.macip = mac_ip;
```

You can also log the `networkInterfaces` to check everything you want:

```
var networkInterfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
console.log( networkInterfaces );
```

NOTE: This method will only get the MAC of the device running the node process. If running from your server, this method will get the MAC address of your server, not of the client making the request.

Answer (score 0):

This is too specific for the original question, but someone else may find this useful. As per other answers, this will not work under all conditions, but it *does* work under a condition as detailed below

#### My Usecase

- Local Network Server only
- Linux Computer

#### My solution

I previously had written a script to seek out a specific computer known to be on a network and known by its mac address.

```bash
homeip=$(sudo arp-scan -lq | grep -i -m 1 $homemac | grep -oP "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+")
```

However, doing this takes a long time (Doing so on a net with subnet `255.255.192.0` can take > 30s!)

That script cached the ip, and could quickly verify the validity of the machine at that point using something like:

```bash
ping -c 1 -w 2 -q $homeip > /dev/null
$(arp -a | grep -m 1 -oP "(?<=\($homeip\) at )([\da-f]{2}:){5}[\da-f]{2}") != "$homemac"
```

So, I decided for my server, as a probably crude form of authentication that I would whitelist certain users by MAC address. Doing so was multi-parted

`resolveip`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

out=$(arp -a | grep -m 1 -oP "(?<=\($1\) at )([\da-f]{2}:){5}[\da-f]{2}")
if [ -z "$out" ]; then
    ping -c 1 -w 1 $1 > /dev/null
    echo $(arp -a | grep -m 1 -oP "(?<=\($1\) at )([\da-f]{2}:){5}[\da-f]{2}")
else
    echo $out
fi
```

Create a wrapper

```js
function getRequestingMAC(requestingIP) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        execFile(`resolveip`, [requestingIP], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            resolve(stdout.toString().trim());
        });
    });

    // Sync-style
    // return execFileSync(`resolveip`, [requestingIP]).toString().trim();
}
```

And use as such:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.hostname === "localhost") {
    } else {
        //match first occurrence of ipv4 ip, not ideal regex
        let ip = (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.socket.remoteAddress).match(/\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}/)[0];
        console.log(ip);
        loop: {
            // check if request came from known ip (my ip)
            const ifaces = require('os').networkInterfaces();
            for (const ifaceKey in ifaces) {
                let iface = ifaces[ifaceKey];
                if (iface.some(it => it.address === ip)) {
                    console.log("Local Request");
                    break loop;
                }
            }
            // else, request mac
            getRequestingMAC(ip).then((ans) => {
                console.log("Request Came From", ans, ip);
                // Give me a banner notif when access attempted
                exec(`zenity --notification --text "Foreign request\n${ans} (${ip}) to ${req.url}"`);
            });
        }
    }
    next();
})
```

This can be changed to wait for the mac before calling `next()` and block non-whitelisted requests.

#### Note

To reiterate, this is not going to work in op's usecase, but *can* and *does* work in my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

MAC addresses are used for node-to-node communication and belong to the data link layer in the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). They are not exposed beyond your local network. The `arp` command, found in the net-tools package in Linux, can list mappings from IP addresses to the MAC addresses of devices within your local network. You can use the following command to find the MAC address of a specific device by its IP address.

```bash
arp -n | grep 192.168.1.2 | grep -Eo '([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}'
```

To execute the above shell script in Node.js, use the `child_process` module:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec("arp -n | grep 192.168.1.2 | grep -Eo '([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}'", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```